# Why does S3 CRR or SRR use Roles to perform replication instead of Bucket Policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-policies

Generally, S3 permissions from other services are managed via a Bucket Policy for example: allowing Cloudtrail to send logs to S3.

However, for [CRR (Cross-Region replication)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html) or [SRR (Same-Region replication)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html), AWS thought of using Roles for S3 permissions - I was just thinking what could be the reason why they never went for putting Bucket Policies each on Source and Target buckets allowing the Principal as `"Principal": {"Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"}`

Could this be just a design preference from AWS or does it solve any other potential challenges?

Comment: One reason could be because its cleaner and easier this way. With bucket policies you would need to create two of them (one for source and one for dest). This is more work. Also you would clutter and obfuscate existing bucket policies. With role there is only 1 IAM entity to manage and create, and your bucket policies are clean or empty. By the way, for replication to different account,  bucket policy is required on destination anyway.

Comment: That explanation really helps !@Marcin

Comment: Maybe there is a better, more technical explanation. Maybe someone can a  concrete answer.